# Remove author page link from Gravatar image

Tags: php, wordpress, function, genesis

I want to unlink the gravatar image. The current gravatar image in the byline is linked with author page and I want to make the gravatar image in the byline of the post without any link.

The code which I am using for showing gravatar in the byline of the post is:

```
add_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'cd_author_gravatar' );
function cd_author_gravatar() {
 if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
 $entry_author = get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'email' ), 64 );
 $author_link = get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) );
 printf( '<div class="author-avatar"><a href="%s">%s</a></div>', $author_link, $entry_author );
 }
}
```

I dont know what to remove in the above code so that I can get only gravatar without any clickable link.

After applying the above code whenever I hover the gravatar image in the byline it shows "example.com/author/admin/"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
add_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'cd_author_gravatar' );
function cd_author_gravatar() {
    if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
        $entry_author = get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'email' ), 64 );
        printf( '<div class="author-avatar">%s</div>', $entry_author );
    }
}
```

I think you will find the difference here ;) You just need to remove line where you load link to authors post to variable $author_link and then remove 'a href' from printf and usage of $author_link.

Edit: Code updated ;)

Comment: really sorry but by mistake I have posted the wrong code here!!

Kindly check it again and give your precious time again.. :(

this is what I am actually using. Check the below code
`add_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'cd_author_gravatar' );
function cd_author_gravatar() {
 if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
 $entry_author = get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'email' ), 64 );
 $author_link = get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) );
 printf( '<div class="author-avatar"><a href="%s">%s</a></div>', $author_link, $entry_author );
 }
}`